# vuejs xmldata to json

Tags: json, xml, vue.js

this will be my first time loading xml data through, but I also want to convert it to json. I have set up my file and looked at some other tutorials on how to do this. I am using axios to make the request. My xml files are actually locally stored files. I was able to console.log the response in, but as soon as I ADDED the PARSESTRING my file broke. Can someone tell me what I am doing incorrect.

```js
        new Vue({
            el: '#xmlData',
            data: { 
                hello: 'Hello World!' 
            },
        created:function(){
            this.getCert();
            this.getEduc();
            this.getHist();
            },

            methods:{
            
     
                   
            getHistory: function(){
                    var vm = this;
                    var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
            axios.get('data/Experience.xml')
                .then(response => {
                    var self = this; 
                    //var xmlText = response.data;
                 parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
                self.events = result
            });        
                   
            });


                },
                getCerti:function(){
                    var vm = this;
            axios.get('data/Certifications.xml')
                .then(response => {
                    var xmlText = response.data;
            });


                },
                getEdu:function(){
            var vm = this;
            axios.get('data/ Education.xml')
                .then(response => {
                    var xmlText = response.data;
            });


                }
            }
        })
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="xmlData">
      <p>{{ hello }}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Comment: What was the error? On a side note, you do not have to use axios to grab a local xml file, you can import it as a object w/ import. That might clean up some things (ie might fix the error). Declaring 'this' to handle the scope issue is a pain sometimes. :/

Comment: error I am getting is reference error: require is not defined

Comment: this project will be loaded on line--I still would need axios in that case - I suppose?

Comment: Yes, if its cross domain you would use some type of fetch call like axios or fetch. In regards to the require error I believe that is a library vue usually leans towards the es6 stuff so what you would do is 'import' that library and use it that way. That error of 'not defined' isnt a vue specific issue and thats a good thing.